# How would i vectorize that 'for' loop in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, loops, vector, vectorization

I have this toy example:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
a = zeros(3, 1);
for p = 1:3
    a(p) = sum(l(p:p+2));
end;
```

This example calculates sum of each 3 elements in 'l', which are close to each other and writes it in 'a'. Now, is it possible to rewrite the same code using vectorization and matrix operations, without 'for' loop? I have tried something similar to:

```
p = 1:3;
a(p) = sum(l(p:p+2));
```

The result was [6, 6, 6], it have calculated sum of the first three elements and wrote it in 'a' on each position. This is only a toy example, but i need to do something similar on 3d 256x256x128 array with 20x20x20 cube elements sum, using 'for' loops was VERY slow there. So, is there a fast way to solve this problem?

**Edit :**
Divakar have suggested me to use my actual case here. Well, here is the most important part of it, which i am trying to rewrite:

**Edit2 :**
Thank you for answer. Understood the idea, removed code above, rewriting it now.

Comment: The vectorized code would vary alot with multi-dimensional arrays, so I suggest you use your actual case here. Also, edit with the expected output for that, so maybe take a small 3D array as an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're describing a basic convolution:

```
a = conv(l,ones(1,3),'valid'); % a should have 3 elements
```

For 3d, use [convn](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convn.html) in a similar fashion with ones(20,20,20)